# Custom Response code and response message in restfull and SOAP services

Tags: api, rest, http

I'm developing Web services restful and SOAP Services, I'm wondering what if I use custom response code and custom response message included in response body and the http response status code in most cases will be returned as (200 ok) so it will be easier to handle errors, I'm wondering if that way is acceptable

Comment: "restful" and "SOAP" are very different things with different requirements.

Comment: Your comment has no added value to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTTP, the definition of a status-line is found in [RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.1.2)

```
status-line = HTTP-version SP status-code SP reason-phrase CRLF
```

reason-phrase turns out to not be particularly important; clients are expected to ignore the reason phrase when processing an HTTP response.

---

> The rest of the response message is to be interpreted in light of the semantics defined for that status code

The status code is an important piece of metadata in the [transfer of documents over a network](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=188s) domain; general purpose clients use it to understand the nature of the HTTP response so that they can do intelligent things.

(Among the intelligent things: automatically following redirects, retrying requests with authentication credentials attached, [cache invalidation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4)).

There's a lot of code out on the internet that you don't control, that understands standardized HTTP semantics.  When you fail to respect the standardized semantics, you introduce a risk that some other code will misunderstand your responses; when that happens, the [blame lies squarely with your implementation](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-tag/2002Apr/0207.html), not the client.

Expressed another way: violating the standard doesn't make things "easier"; what it does is move around where the work needs to be done.  Abiding the standard is doing your fair share of the work; offloading your share of the work onto your clients is rude.

---

That said, if you look carefully, there are plenty of spaces where you will find that people do deliberately violate the standards (I see this when working on health checks).  The dreadful consequences of violating the standard are not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

Use appropriate status codes for appropriate errors. Both SOAP and REST should use 4xx and 5xx where they make sense. If you are looking for a good standard response type for REST, go for [application/problem+json](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807), for SOAP use SOAP's standards.

Clients for each should still behave correctly if they get a HTTP error, but don't support/understand the response body.